The commands in my discord python cog aren't running, there is no error, it's just not giving output
I'm pretty new to python and discord.py, but i'm tryna learn how cogs work. I've tried sooo many things but I'm stuck, since I'm not sure in which piece of code the problem is. It doesn't return any error, it simply doesn't respond to the !ping command. The other commands (not in a cog) work just fine.
Here's all the code referring to the !ping command in bot.py:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import os

BOT_TOKEN='my token'
CHANNEL_ID='my id'


bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())
session=Session()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Hello! Bot is ready.')
    channel=bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send('Hello! Bot is ready. My prefix is "!"')

async def main():
    await bot.start(BOT_TOKEN)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

Here's the code for ping.py in the cogs folder:
from discord.ext import commands

class ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

@commands.command()
async def ping(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("pong")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(ping(bot))

I've tried looking for answers in the internet and re-reading the code but i'm just stuck.

I never use discord.py but I find it strange. You say that bot.py refers to ping.py, but bot.py not even imports ping.py! How is library supposed to know that you created that ping command?

From a glance at this code, it looks like you meant for async def ping ... to be a method of class ping(commands.Cog). Try indenting that function so that it is correctly recognized.

This is a very common problem here on the forum: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78140517/error-for-command-not-found-discord-bot-in-python/78144362#78144362

Thanks everyone!! @brandizzi it's the part starting with async def on_ready(): for filename in os.listdir('./cogs') but it works now:)

The setup function is asynchronous as well as the add_cog method:
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(ping(bot))

